# XML DataContractDeserialization HELP needed

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, collections, datacontractserializer

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Responses>
    <ResponseList>
      <Response type="XXX">
        <Foo>YYYY</Foo>
        <Bar>ZZZZ</Bar>
      </Response>
    </ResponseList>
</Responses>
```

what should my classes look like so that I can deserialize the string into an object (I am using a DataContractSerializer)

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
[Serializable]
public class Responses : DataContainer
{
    [DataMember]
    public ResponseCollection ResponseList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Response : DataContainer 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResponseCollection : List<Response>
{
}
```

[edit]
I was actually able to get it working with the DataContractSerializer....My goal was to utilize the DataContractSerializer to deserialize an XML string (a response), into an object, and I was getting NULLs for both properties (foo & bar).

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Responses : DataContainer
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ResponseList")]
    public Response[] Response { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Response : DataContainer
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When faced with problems like this in the past, I've build a class that matches the xml definition as closely as possible, create an instance and populate it with the given test data, then serialize it.

Compare the result against the given xml input and tweak till it will pass your tests.  You should then be able to de-serialize into that class.  Im also curious to see if there is an easier method.

Comment: You can't do what you want using `DataContractSerializer`. It doesn't use attributes.

Comment: @John Saunders - Actually, `DataContractSerializer` does use attributes, as the sample code in the question shows.  See [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx), [DataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx), and [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)

Comment: @Nathan: I mean XML Attributes.

Comment: @John Saunders - ah.  I misinterpreted.  Have you seen http://lordzoltan.blogspot.com/2010/09/serializing-to-attributes-in-wcf-with.html ?  Not necessarily pretty, but it looks like you can actually hack xml attribute support into it. (Though I haven't tested this myself)

Comment: @Nathan: that article doesn't apply, as it does not use the data contract serializer at all; not really.

Answer (score 2):

(this answer pre-dates the edit that clarified that DataContractSerializer was desired)

If I understand the example correctly, then as below. Note: the other attributes do no harm, but aren't used by XmlSerializer - I've only shown those used by XmlSerializer.

```
[XmlRoot("Responses")]
public class TxTNotifyResponse : DataContainer
{
    [XmlArray("ResponseList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Response")]
    public MsgResponseCollection MsgResponseList { get; set; }
}

public class MsgResponse : DataContainer 
{
    [XmlElement("Foo")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
}

public class MsgResponseCollection : List<MsgResponse>
{
}
```

If that doesn't work (and I haven't tested it), try using a separate DTO model. The easiest way is to put the data in an XML filE (say, your.xml), and use (at the command prompt):

```
xsd.exe your.xml
xsd.exe your.xsd /classes
```

Which will write your.cs

Comment: Thats a good response, but I think I made the mistake in posting using an XML serializer.  I have an XML string and using a DataContractSerializer, which works like so...

  public T ReadObject(string objectString)
  {
   var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(_encoding.GetBytes(objectString));
   var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(memoryStream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
   var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
   var obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(reader, true);
   reader.Close();
   return obj;
  }

Comment: @Todd - I am not clear anymore what your question actually is.  The code in your comment is not included in your question. However, you have code that shows you are calling the deserialization methods (`ReadObject(...)') of the DataContractSerializer.  Is that giving you incorrect results? An Exception? What exactly is your problem that you are asking for help with?

Comment: @Todd DataContractSerializer does not allow the same fine-grained control over XML. My advice: if the XML layout matters: use XmlSerializer.

Comment: @MarcGravell - I will never serialize back into XML, so the layout is not so much an issue here.  I just want a nice way to parse an HTTP response that is in XML format...does anyone have better suggestions?

Comment: @Todd layout is just as important when deserializing